# SVG not displaying in Firefox

Tags: html, angularjs, svg, charts

I am using ChartAngular to create a cart in my angular app. This works fine in chrome and even IE8 but in Firefox sometimes it just displays a blank div. Sometimes it works some times it doesn't. I can't find a pattern.

Javascript:

```
$scope.isLoaded = false;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.isLoaded = true;
            alert("it should be loaded");
        },200)

$scope.chart_options = {
            data: $scope.lineGraphData.values,
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y']
            ,labels: []
            ,hideHover: 'always' 
            ,pointSize: 0
            ,ymax:1

        };
```

HTML:

```
<div id='line-example' ng-click="expandChart()" style="height: 150px;  width:400px;" class=" no-padding no-margin small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">

        <linechart  ng-if="isLoaded" style="overflow:visible" id="line-example" options="chart_options"></linechart>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any questions please ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create an example demonstrating the problem on i.e. plunker, fiddle, jsbin...

Comment: This is not HTML, but some Angular template. You should post the rendered HTML instead to debug such problems…